# trying to echo value of method php

Tags: php, html

I've made a php page which will make a form and post information to itself. I then make an object with it which I run through a method that I want to return/echo a string here's my code.

```
<?php
include_once 'checkLogin.php';
$action='';//this will store what the user wants to do
if(isset($_GET['savings'])){$action='save';}
if(isset($_GET['depreciation'])){$action='deprec';}
$time=$_POST['time'];//get the values from the form below
$interest=$_POST['interest'];
$InitialSum=$_POST['InitialSum'];
  //depreciation and savings can be done on the same page
class Information{
  function __construct($time,$interest,$InitialSum){
    $this->time=$time;
    $this->interest=$interest;
    $this->InitialSum=$InitialSum;
  }
  function CalcSave(){
    $totalAmt=$InitialSum*($interest*100);//the total amount, this will count as one year
    for ($x=0;$x<$time;$x++){//therefore this should only do 1 less than the total
      $totalAmt=($interest*100)*$totalAmmt;//after another year
    }
  return'After '.$time.' years your savings will be worth '.$totalAmt.'.';
    }
  function CalcDeprec(){
    $totalAmt=$InitialSum*$interest;
    for ($x=0;$x<$time;$x++){//therefore this should only do 1 less than the total
      $totalAmt=$interest*$totalAmmt;//after another year
    }
  return 'After'.$time.'years your asset will be worth '.$totalAmt.'.';
    }
}
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
Initial Amount: <input type="number" name="InitialSum"><br>
Interest: <input type="number" name="interest"><br>
How long: <input type='number' name='time'><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<p>
  <?php
  $user=new Information($time,$interest,$InitialSum);//this creates the user object
  if ($action=='save'){
    $user->CalcSave();//this will run the method since user is the object
    echo $result;
  }
  if ($action=='deprec'){
    $user->CalcDeprec();
    echo $result;
  }
  ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't mind if it goes to a different page but ideally I would like it to be echoed onto the page. I'm not getting any errors from it and I am not very experienced with OOP in php.
**Edit** I've tried `$result = $user->CalcSave();
echo $result;`
and

```
echo $user->CalcSave();
```

but it reloads the same page without the

```
?action=depreciation
```

at the end of the page and nothing is echoed.

Comment: `echo $user->CalcSave();` and `echo $user->CalcDeprec();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = $user->CalcSave();
echo $result;
```

and:

```
$result = $user->CalcDeprec();
echo $result;
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Or simply `echo $user->CalcSave();` and forget about creating an unnecessary scalar variable